# React-native : Is it safe to let secret keys in app source code?

Tags: react-native, woocommerce

I want to use WooCommerce API from a mobile app (react-native). I saw from the docs that we can easily do that by setting an api key. However I'm wondering, is it safe to add those keys right into my react app code? (is it possible for a user to see in the app source code to steal those keys)?

Since those key gives a lot of permission over the shop. I just want a user of my app to be able to add product in his cart and to pay for them. And also to retrieve product informations for my app.

Comment: No, it is not safe to add your Woocommerce keys directly into your React app code. React apps are typically client-side applications that are executed on the user's browser. Adding sensitive information like API keys directly into the app's code exposes them to potential security risks. Instead, you should handle API keys securely on the server-side. In a React app, you can create an API proxy on your server that communicates with the Woocommerce API using the sensitive keys.